# spring boot: error message "Request method 'POST' not supported" after migration from jdk1.8 to jdk10

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I specify that the program worked well with java 1.8. However, as soon as I migrated to java 10, nothing works now and I get this error message every time I try to execute an http request in postman

[capture console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fty41.png)

I just added two more images.
the first is the post method and the second is the response in postman

[la methode POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgG7O.png)

[la réponse dans postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAlte.png)

Comment: Show the code with POST method implementation and also capture from Postman

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please post code as code not as images (or worse links to images).

Comment: @RafałSokalski I just edited my post with your comments.

Comment: @M.Deinum I just edited my post with your comments.

Comment: @Community I just edited my post with your comments.

Comment: I still see links to image of code, no code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem

the concern was that when migrating to a version of spring boot compatible with java 10, we have certain ways of declaring the properties in the application.properties file which change.

example:
the program no longer recognizes:
**server.contextPath=...**
he now recognizes
**server.servlet.context-path=...**

suddenly the error message: "*Request method 'POST' not supported*" is due to the fact that the context path was not found. it returned empty.

thank !!